# Calculate and print SHA256 hash of a file using OpenSSL

Tags: c, cryptography, openssl, sha256

I'm trying to write a C function using OpenSSL/libcrypto to calculate the SHA256 sum of a file. I'm basing my code on Adam Lamer's c++ example [here](http://adamlamers.com/?p=5).

Here's my code:

```
int main (int argc, char** argv)
{
    char calc_hash[65];

    calc_sha256("file.txt", calc_hash);
}

int calc_sha256 (char* path, char output[65])
{
    FILE* file = fopen(path, "rb");
    if(!file) return -1;

    char hash[SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH];
    SHA256_CTX sha256;
    SHA256_Init(&sha256);
    const int bufSize = 32768;
    char* buffer = malloc(bufSize);
    int bytesRead = 0;
    if(!buffer) return -1;
    while((bytesRead = fread(buffer, 1, bufSize, file)))
    {
        SHA256_Update(&sha256, buffer, bytesRead);
    }
    SHA256_Final(hash, &sha256);

    sha256_hash_string(hash, output);
    fclose(file);
    free(buffer);
    return 0;
}      

void sha256_hash_string (char hash[SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH], char outputBuffer[65])
{
    int i = 0;

    for(i = 0; i < SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH; i++)
    {
        sprintf(outputBuffer + (i * 2), "%02x", hash[i]);
    }

    outputBuffer[64] = 0;
}
```

The problem is this....take a look at the calculated sums below for an example file:

```
Known good SHA256: 6da032d0f859191f3ec46a89860694c61e65460d54f2f6760b033fa416b73866
Calc. by my code:  6dff32ffff59191f3eff6affff06ffff1e65460d54ffff760b033fff16ff3866
```

I also get * stack smashing detected * when the code is finished executing.

Does anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: why const int bufSize is fixed with the size of 32768 ? it could be more or less

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Looks like there are a lot of '0xff' blocks in your output, and the corresponding blocks in the good string have the high bit set ... maybe a sign extension problem somewhere.

Does making:

```
char hash[SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH];
```

unsigned, like:

```
unsigned char hash[SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH];
```

help?  (Especially in the signature of `sha256_hash_string`.)

Comment: That fixed it! Thank you! I'm on Ubuntu using gcc.

Comment: My comment about little-endianess was wrong, so I deleted it ...  Adam had the right explanation about 8 bytes being printed every time the input was negative.   This is a good example of why, when dealing with "bytes" and not "string characters" you should use 'unsigned char' (or uint8 or one of its variants).  The bare 'char' should be reserved for ASCII characters.

Answer (score 12):

You're printing out a *signed* `char` as an integer.  If the byte is negative, it get's converted to a `signed int` (the *default argument promotions* in the call to `sprintf`), and then that gets converted to an `unsigned int` (via the `%x` format specifier) and printed out.

So, the byte `A0` is -96 as a signed byte, which gets converted to -96 as a `signed int`, which is 0xFFFFFFA0 in hex, so it gets printed out as FFFFFFA0.

To fix this, case each byte to an `unsigned char` before printing:

```
sprintf(..., (unsigned char)hash[i]);
```

You're getting the warning about stack smashing because there's a signed byte near the end of the hash, so you're writing the 8 bytes FFFFFFB7 at offset 58 when you intended to only write 2 bytes.  This results in a [*buffer overflow*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow), which happens to be detected here because the compiler likely inserted a guard area or security cookie in the stack before the return value, and it detected that that guard area was inadvertently modified.

Comment: That's it! Thanks for the explaination!!